# Duplicates on file_put_contents with uniqid() filename

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, file-put-contents

I create file with `file_put_contents(uniqid().'.txt', '123')` and it works as I expect from it, but only when I visit this script page manually. If i do it via fetch it creates 2 `.txt` files with a `uniqid()` names. Definetly have no idea why.

Script that creates files

```
<?
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    
    var_dump(file_put_contents(uniqid().'.txt', '123'));
?>
```

The fetch

```
fetch('http://tst/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: '',
}).then(res => {
    return res.text();
}).then(json => {
    console.log(json);
});
```

**EDIT**

The reason of this behavior is two separate `fetch()`, but I don't understand why this is happening. Screenshot of network tab is below
[image]

Comment: The only logical explanation for this is that the client is making two separate calls to `fetch()`. Check the network tab of your dev tools and you'll see two separate requests.

Comment: @AlexHowansky That's right. And I can't understand why. Maybe, you can explain?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with PHP or file_put_contents. It's purely client side, in whatever JS code is surrounding this call to fetch(). Use your JS debugger to step through it and see why it's being run twice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was very interesting to read.

So the reason of this, as Alex said, was calling `fetch ()` twice.

But why it called twice? That what's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) says:

> Unlike “simple requests” (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data.

So all I had to do was check the received request for the presence of the data that I am transferring